# I rewired my two bulb ceiling light

Tags: electrical

one of the bulbs was not working.  I took the wiring apart and rewired them in series Now neither one works.

Comment: A/C bulbs in most systems are wired in parallel, not series. And, if the filament in one bulb was out, neither will work in series.

Answer (score 3):

The sockets should be wired in parallel, not series.

The bulbs will be designed for whatever Mains voltage is used in your location.  If you put two in series, then each bulb gets half the voltage.  If you have "old-fashioned" filament bulbs, the may each light dimly.  If you have modern (CFL, LED) bulbs, they might not light at all because the circuitry isn't getting enough power.

Also, in series, if one fails with an open circuit, then no power gets to the other bulb and they both go out.

I suggest wiring them back in parallel, and then testing with new bulbs.  If one bulb doesn't light up, then swap their locations.  See if the problem follows the bulb or the socket...

Good luck!